# Loading a JSON file from another job's archive into a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to store a JSON file as the output of one job, and read that JSON in and parse it for use in a pipeline in a different job. I'm having trouble getting the JSON from the first job into my workspace so I can read it.

This mentions reading in a JSON, but not how to get it into the workspace = [Pass Jenkins Pipeline parameters from a Jenkins job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031673/pass-jenkins-pipeline-parameters-from-a-jenkins-job)

I see some suggestions that involve adding build steps (URL SCM plugin), but adding build steps doesn't seem available in my pipeline job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [archiveArtifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts) and [copyArtifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/). You would archive the JSON file in one job and then copy it from in the other.

Edit:

In a pipeline you would do something like:

```
copyArtifacts(projectName: 'sourceproject')
```

or

```
copyArtifacts(projectName: 'downstream', selector: lastSuccessful())
```

You can look it up here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

Comment: so the archiving artifacts portion works fine. I did check out copyArtifacts, but it's a build step that takes in from other jobs and puts it into the current job. The issue is that in a pipeline job I do not have the ability to add a build step from the GUI. Maybe I just need to understand how to do that via code in the jenkinsFile, and I'm trying to find how to do that using copyArtifacts but am struggling.